# How do i align 3 images in a bootstrap card so that they are side by side?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do you align  3 images so that they side by side in a single bootstrap card? i am able to align the first 2 images but the 3rd image keeps appearing underneath the first two. Been trying all day to get the 3rd one so slot in beside the first two images.

```
        <div class="well text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">Club Hiarchy:</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\BM.jpg" alt="css_logo"  class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\TM.jpg" alt="ccs_logo"  class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\TM.jpg" alt="ccs_logo"   class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `col-md-6` for 3 images on a 12 column grid! 6x2 = 12 so it will obviously show two images side by side and thrid on underneath. You should use `col-md-4` because 4x3 = 12.

try this:

```html
<div class="well text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">Club Hiarchy:</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\BM.jpg" alt="css_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\TM.jpg" alt="ccs_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="#"><img src=".\Pictures\TM.jpg" alt="ccs_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Rod little</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> freddrf34 trrfefwerrf frewferfrf erf ref </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happened? You unchecked the answer.